# Missing DLL files in \bin folder after downloading fully-working solution to a second machine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, webforms, azure-devops

I'm trying to download and run working branch onto a second machine from Azure DevOps (formerly VisualStudio.com).

#### Main machine (VS2017 Pro):

1. SolutionABC builds and runs perfectly
2. Branched to SolutionABC-Branch with small changes (external to this issue)
3. SolutionABC-Branch builds and runs perfectly
4. SolutionABC-Branch checked in

#### Second machine (VS2019 Pro):

1. SolutionABC downloads, builds and runs perfectly
2. SolutionABC-Branch downloads, but won't build:

Tracing the errors back through the Errors dialog, I get this:

> Warning   BC40056
>
> Namespace or type specified in the **Imports
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory'** doesn't contain any
>   public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type
>   is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the
>   imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

A quick Google search leads me [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/namespace-or-type-specified-in-the-project-level-imports-qualifiedelementname), so following the instructions there are indeed some issues:

[image]

Firstly, how can I solve this please?

Secondly, how does this happen when the parent solution from which this is branched runs perfectly on this machine?

### Update

It appears that many of the project references (both to other projects in the solution, and also to Microsoft DLL's) are also missing.  Through desperation I xcopied the Microsoft DLL's from the initial project to the branched project.  This has fixed the issue, but my questions are still unanswered...

### Solution

The problem turned out to be the file/path length limitation of VSTS/TFS.  Relocating my local repo to a shorter directory name (e.g. `C:\TFS`) fixed the issue.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Use of that assembly is new to the branch, which has added this assembly which looks like its part of *Azure SDK for .NET* - is that something which isn't installed on machine 2? Possibly a component that's not been opted for on the 2019 install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Missing DLL files in \bin folder after downloading fully-working solution to a second machine

AFAIK, this issue should not related to TFS/Azure Devops, it is more related to the small changes or the environment settings. Although you think it is (outside the current issue), it may cause the this issue to arise where you can't see/think it.

To resolved this issue, we need to troubleshooting it:

Since the parent solution from which this is branched runs perfectly on the Second machine (VS2019 Pro), we could create a new branch without that small changes, then check if still have this issue?

Then, add those changes and check if you have this issue again.

Note: Try to remove the references from the SolutionABC-Branch solution on the second machine and add them back to check if this issue has been resolved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've updated VS to 16.2.1.  I branched the original solution (with no changes), and downloaded to the second machine. An error now occurs during download that did not occur previously, `TF400889 The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters` (The ActiveDirectory DLL's in question).  So... why is that only an occurence on machine 2?  More importantly, how is this overcome given that the majority of those characters are generated by Microsoft's naming conventions?

Comment: @EvilDr, Have you tried to save the local repo in the root of C/D disk?

Comment: Not yet.  I appreciate that I'm going to have to remap my folder mappings, and also rename the branch to something much shorter.  Despite this, I still don't have many characters to play with when the Microsoft DLL file name is 147 characters.  Is there no workaround for this limitation other than shorter solution/projects/branch names?  Also does that problem occur with Git?

Comment: @EvilDr, I am sorry to reply so late, I am stuck in other threads until now. Yes, this is the TFVC limitation:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/naming-restrictions#version-control-paths. We have to tweaking your file/folder structure to make this work.

Comment: @EvilDr, Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for checking back.  Relocating the local workspace folder to a short path (e.g. `C:\TFS\`) fixed the issue.  Its an unfortunate limitation but at least I found the solution.  Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

### How to solve this:

Use the nuget package for the [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/)

### What is causing this:

I would bet that this is pointing out a discrepancy between those two machines. Look in the directory on box 1 listed in the properties of the reference and check that the assembly is there. Verify it is in the same path on box 2. Also check the GAC on both machines. VS/MSBuild tries to be as smart as possible when looking for those assemblies and if the hint path says one thing, and it isn't found there, but the assembly is registered, the build will go through fine.

Comment: Okay this is weird.  I checked the packages directory on the branched solution, and the DLL files were indeed there, despite the references box in VS not seeing them.  It seems the packages folder is correctly branched as part of the solution branch.  I can also see them in the packages directory on both solutions (original and branched) when I browse the files online via visualstudio.com.

Comment: I think @Leo Liu-MSFT has found the root issue (path length limitations) above.  But thank you anyway for your kind and valued input.